# Do these species differ from humans in any other way according to canon?

Tags: star-trek

In *Star Trek* canon at least 3 species have a humanoid appearance except for small differences:

- [Barkonian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barkonian), have a pattern on their forehead.
- [Bajoran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran), have horizontal creases across their noses.
- [Kaelon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kaelon), have dark lines on the sides of their heads.

In canon, other than appearance do these races differ from humans in any other way? For example, according to the Memory Alpha Wiki, Kaelons are immune to Betazoid telepathy.

I didn't include [Betazoid](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Betazoid) because it's pretty established how they are different from humans.

I'm **not** looking for differences in society, how their technology is different from ours, or beliefs, but on [physiology](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/248791.php).

Comment: There appear to be three distinct questions here.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I thought something looked off, those fullstops make things look so much prettier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bajorans differ physiologically by the way they give birth. According to the DS9 episode, "Body Parts," Bajoran women only carry their young for 5 months, during which a network of blood vessels is formed between the mother and the fetus, making it almost impossible to remove a fetus before it's birthed naturally. While pregnant, Bajoran women sneeze instead of feeling nauseous.

The other species listed are only briefly on the show, so there's little canonical evidence of any internal differences. However, it's safe to assume that their physiology is better matched to their planet of origin, just like Human physiology is matched to Earth.

Answer (score 6):

[Barkonians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barkonian) were a minor character in a single episode on a non-warp-capable world, so there isn't a whole lot of detail. There isn't even an entry for them on Memory Beta.

[Kaelon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kaelon), properly "Kaelonians", according to Memory Alpha's background notes. Those same notes indicate the decorations are cosmetic, not biological. There is an entry, but no pertinent information on [Memory Beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Kaelon).

[Bajorans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran) are actually *covered in the source you linked to*.

- The Bajoran heart was mirrored along a horizontal axis, unlike the Human heart, which was mirrored along a vertical axis.
- Bajoran women gestated for only five months, forming an intricate network of blood vessels between the mother and the fetus. During the pregnancy, Bajoran women were frequently afflicted by bouts of uncontrollable sneezing, roughly analogous to Human women experiencing morning sickness during pregnancy.

Comment: The last bullet point is also stated in the other answer, but other wise a good answer.